# Как создать иконку моего приложения в строке StatusBar

Tags: java, android, icon

Никак не могу найти как создать маленькую иконку для моего приложения именно в самом верху экрана. (НЕ иконку для рабочего стола)
На картинке снизу я указал красными овалами интересующие меня примеры. 
Перечеркнул же то, что постоянно нахожу вместо того, что ищу, но оно меня абсолютно не интересует. 
Очень желательно пример по проще, так как я начинающий. Спасибо.

Использую Android Studio, Java для телефонов с андроидами 4.4.4 и 6.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: без уведомления не будет иконки я думаю

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже так подметил, что оно, вероятно, всё неизбежно повязано.

Answer (score 1):

Для определения иконки в баре уведомлений используется `setSmallIcon()`, так ее используют

```java
new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground) // setSmallIcon() для определения иконки
```

[Вот документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder) 
[Вот урок по его использованию](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/509-android-notifications-osnovy.html)

Comment: Всё получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: вы можете отметить ответ как решение нажав на галочку